# How Can i Round this Series

Tags: asp.net

I have to display ratings and for that i need increments as follows:

If the number is 1.0 it should be equal to 1

If the number is 1.1 should be equal to 1

If the number is 1.2 should be equal to 2

If the number is 1.3 should be equal to 2

If the number is 1.4 should be equal to 2

If the number is 1.5 should be equal to 2

If the number is 1.6 should be equal to 2

If the number is 1.7 should be equal to 2

If the number is 1.8 should be equal to 2.0

If the number is 1.9 should be equal to 2.0

If the number is 2.0 should be equal to 2.0

If the number is 2.1 should be equal to 2.0

and so on...

Is there a simple way to compute the required values?

Comment: What have you tried thus far? This is a Q&A website), and from the looks of it you haven't tried anything yet. It would help you and us if you added what you have tried this far.

Comment: i am try to round these values..when i do this 1.5,1.6,1.7 round by 1.5 , instead i want to round by 2

Comment: pseudocode: `if nummber < 1.2 then output 1 else output 2`? It is not clear what you want. Is there supposed to be something different between "2" and "2.0"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Math.Floor()` function:

In `C#` syntax:

```
double number = 1.2;
double new_number = Math.Floor(number + 0.8);

//Console.WriteLine(new_number);
```

Comment: Math.Floor always rounds down. You want Math.Round

Comment: @AshleyMedway: How do you get 2.0 from `Math.Round(1.2)` like your way? You have to use the same technique by adding `0.8` but that `would give you 3 when number is 1.9`.

Comment: Sorry my bad, that will teach me not to read the question correctly... UP VOTE :P

Comment: using this method the number 1.9 round as 3

Comment: Yes, if you use Math.Round() function but **Impossible with Floor()** because `1.9 + 0.8 => 2.7` *and* `Math.Floor(2.7) => 2`.

Comment: Guys please comment a reason for a downvote. I think this is what exactly OP expecting.

Comment: is it possible to round 1.1 as 2.

Comment: You cannot round but if you use `Math.Ceiling(1.1)` you will get `2.0`. If you need to use `x.1` *as* `(x+1).0` then use `Math.Floor(x+0.9)`.